# Frequency of work out

Tags: workout-routines

How often one must  work out in a week to get maximum from it? Is it ok to workout seven days a week. 
What should be the duration of rest between two workouts? 
what is the amount of sleep required during workout? Does sleeping for more than 8hours help?
Does duration of workout depend on how much heavy weight you lift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How often one must work out in a week to get maximum from it?

This has no definitive answer. It depends entirely on you, your body, your diet, your sleep, your workout program.

> Is it ok to workout seven days a week.

Yes, but don't. If you continue to strain your muscles and central nervous system (CNS) without giving them a break, they WILL falter, and they will not grow stronger, but instead grow weaker.

This is because muscles grow AFTER the workout, when you rest and eat.

> What should be the duration of rest between two workouts?

See answer to first question. This depends on all those other factors.

A good place to start is to workout every other day. That is, give your body approximately 48 hours between each workout.

> what is the amount of sleep required during workout?

See first answer.

> Does sleeping for more than 8hours help?

The more the better, but 8 hours is generally fine.

> Does duration of workout depend on how much heavy weight you lift?

That's entirely up to you. After a set of heavy bench press, for example, you might feel fatigue in your entire body. This is because your CNS has been under a lot of pressure. But it's still up to you whether you continue the workout, or go home and reap the rewards of your work.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Consistency is key in making and maintaining gains. Working out once a week every week is much better then working out 7 days every other month or so. If you start right of the bat with a 7 days regime you are likely to burn out mentally in a short time. Duration of workouts largely depends on how much rest you like to take between reps and sets. Personally I take 1 minute between sets and 3 minutes between exercises. My 6 exercise plans take about an hour to complete. I find that to be optimal for me, if they get too long it gets harder to find time and get motivated. I advocate for 2-3 gym sessions a week. Unless you are an athlete preparing for competition one really don't need any more then that to keep healthy and in great shape. A 7 day program is possible just make sure to design it so each muscle group gets at least 2 days of rest after targetting. You will not see any gains if you simply keep tearing them down without giving them a chance to rebuild back up